# how to create delay between groups of requests in jmeter?

Tags: loops, jmeter, delay

I'm trying to implement the following in jmeter: send 100 identical requests, wait for 1 minute, send the same requests again...for 30 min. I can't add delay/waiter/pause between groups of requests in jmeter. Timers don't work since they introduce those pauses between requests, not groups of requests. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Timers obey JMeter's [Scoping rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules):

> Some elements in the test trees are strictly hierarchical (Listeners, Config Elements, Post-Processors, Pre-Processors, Assertions, Timers)

You need to put Timer **under** [Flow Control Action (was: Test Action )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)
Which will be after 100 requests

> For variable delays, set the pause time to zero, and add a Timer as a child.

Comment: Now called "Flow Control Action" (located under "Sampler").  When you place one inside a Loop Controller it will execute all your HTTP requests sequentially and then "sleep" for a configurable amount of time before starting the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter Test Action]
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the Test Action sampler and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

The synchronizing timer will act as a "rendezvous" point when all threads will "meet" and wait together for 60 seconds prior to moving on.